# how to move from gcmIntentService to fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, google-cloud-messaging, fragment

I want to open Notifications fragment on receiving a notification. Once i click on receiving notification i want to move to Notification fragment.

Here is my code :

```
if(chatType.equals("7")){

    notification.contentView = contentView;
    /*  
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
            new Intent(this, NotificationsActivity.class).putExtra("json_msg",msg).
                    setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK
                            |Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP), PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    notification.contentIntent = contentIntent;
    */

    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent.putExtra("json_msg",msg),0);
    notification.contentIntent = contentIntent;

    /*
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.containerView,new NotificationsFragment()).commit();
    */

    // notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR; //Do not clear the notification
    notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS; // LED
    notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE; //Vibration
    notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND; // Sound
    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
    mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
} else {
    notification.contentView = contentView;
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
                new Intent(this, ChatActivity.class).putExtra("json_msg",msg).
                        setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK
                                |Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP), PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    notification.contentIntent = contentIntent;

    // notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR; //Do not clear the notification
    notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS; // LED
    notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE; //Vibration
    notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND; // Sound
    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

    mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You would need to go to launch the fragment from the activity your notification intent is set for. So lets say your notification opens up the MainActivity you could call a method like this in onCreate or onNewIntent

So for example

```
    @Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
       super.onNewIntent(intent);
       loadNotificationFragment()
    }

    public void loadNotificationFragment() {
    if (getIntent() != null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction() 
                .replace(R.id.fragment_container, NotificationFragment.newInstance(getIntent().getStringExtra("jso_msg")))
                .addToBackStack(null)
                .commit();
    }
}
```

Comment: Cannot resolve method 'newInstance(java.lang.String)'

Comment: @PrachiKarapurkar any luck?

Comment: getting error at  public static Fragment newInstance(String jso_msg) {
    }   in NotificationsFragment

Comment: its going in mainActivity but notificationFragment is not opening